# Rails minitest failed in has_many validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I've got simple belongs_to/has_many relation like below:

```
class AppropriatenessTestResult < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :appropriateness_test_question
end

class AppropriatenessTestQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appropriateness_test_results, dependent: :destroy
end
```

migration for `AppropriatenessTestResult`:

```
class CreateAppropriatenessTestResults < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :appropriateness_test_results do |t|
      t.references :appropriateness_test_question, foreign_key: true, index: { name: 'idx_appropriateness_test_question_id' }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to test if relations are set properly. To do so I wrote Minitest for `AppropriatenessTestQuestion` model:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AppropriatenessTestQuestionTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context 'associations' do
    should have_many(:appropriateness_test_question)
  end
end
```

which gives me an error:

> Failure:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     AppropriatenessTestQuestionTest#test_: associations should have many appropriateness_test_question.  Expected AppropriatenessTestQuestion to have a has_many association called appropriateness_test_question (no association called appropriateness_test_question)

What did I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! I accidentally checked associations of `appropriateness_test_questions` instead of `appropriateness_test_results`

should be:

```
should have_many(:appropriateness_test_results)
```

instead of:

```
should have_many(:appropriateness_test_questions)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
should have_many(:appropriateness_test_questions)
```

The has_many association uses the plural, good luck!